# What should be the angle from horizontal (in anticlockwise direction) for which range is maximum for a projectile projected from a height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I was studying about projectiles in the section of 2D Kinematics, where I came to know about the ground to ground projectiles. I got to know that for having maximum range in ground to ground projectiles (such as in the case of throwing a javelin), there should be an angle of 45° with the ground. But I also came to know that, if the same thing is projected in from a height, the angle, for reaching maximum range, will not be 45°. 
 I tried finding that angle, but it got very much complex and I could not get any result. 
 Can you please tell me how to derive the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juhi!
First, consider the motion equations by axis:

$x(t)=v_0 t \cos{\theta}$

$y(t)=h+v_0 t \sin{\theta}-gt^2/2$

being $h$ the initial height, $v_0$ the launch velocity, $\theta$ the launch angle, $t$ the time and, $(x;y)$ the coordinate of the projectile.
If you separate $t$ from first equation and substitute it in the second, you obtain the *trajectory equation*.

$y(x) = h + x \tan{\theta} - gx^2 (1+\tan^2{\theta})/(2v_0^2)$

Since you study the range $R$, in that point, $y(R)=0$, so you must to resolve a quadratic equation.

$0=h + R \tan{\theta} - gR^2(1+\tan^2{\theta})/(2v_0^2)$

When you solve the above, obtain two solutions (positive and negative), obviously you take the positive.

$R=v_0^2\sin{2\theta}/(2g)\left(1+\sqrt{1+2gh/(v_0^2\sin^2{\theta})\right)$

Note if $h=0$, the above equation is reduced to the known formula for horizontal ground launch.
Now, you can apply the derivative $\frac{dR}{d\theta}=0$ for obtaining the optimal angle for maximal or minimal range. Obviously, for minimal range ($R=0$), the angle is $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: I got some of the idea, but it would be highly helpful if you can edit the last equation to make it more clear! It's showing along with some "coding" language!

Comment: It's LaTex language for editing text. You can see better this equation on webpage. Here in the Stackoverflow app it doesn't seen clear. Regards!

Comment: Actually I am using it on the webpage only. I tried using desktop site also... but it's the same!

Comment: If it is possible, then please write the above equation here in comments in words. Here what I am getting is that, R = (v zero square times sin2theta upon 2g) multiplied by [1 + square root of {1 plus (2gh/v zero square times sin square theta)}]. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, Juhi.